Swagger.json output has extra response content type
I have a controller that outputs this in swagger
"responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Sample output response",
        "content": {
          "text/plain": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/testResponse"
            }
          },
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/testResponse"
            }
          },
          "text/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/testResponse"
            }
          }
        }
      },

here's my controller
  public async Task<IActionResult> TestController(string id, [FromQuery, Range(1, 100)] int limit)

  try
  {

      var response = await service.getServiceResponseAsync(id, limit);

      return Ok(response );
  }
  catch (InvalidRequestException ex)
  {
      return BadRequest(CreateErrorResponse("Invalid request", ex.PropertyName, ex.Message));
  }
  catch (NotFoundException ex)
  {
      return NotFound(CreateErrorResponse("Not found", ex.PropertyName, ex.Message));
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      return StatusCode(500, CreateErrorResponse("Server error", "server", ex.Message));
  }

As you can see it has the text/json and text/plain in the content.. I am not sure how to get rid of this in my controller.
